# Finding all the 3-combinations of the output of for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop

I feel like this is supposed to be very straightforward but I am unable to work it out.

I have a very simple piece of c++ code.

```
for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; ++a)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b)
            {
                if (a != b)
                {
                    std::cout << "k: " << k  << " a: " << a  << " b: " << b  << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
```

The output will have 24 lines like this

```
k: 0 a: 0 b: 1
k: 0 a: 0 b: 2
k: 0 a: 0 b: 3
k: 0 a: 1 b: 0
k: 0 a: 1 b: 2
k: 0 a: 1 b: 3
k: 0 a: 2 b: 0
k: 0 a: 2 b: 1
k: 0 a: 2 b: 3
k: 0 a: 3 b: 0
k: 0 a: 3 b: 1
k: 0 a: 3 b: 2
k: 1 a: 0 b: 1
k: 1 a: 0 b: 2
k: 1 a: 0 b: 3
k: 1 a: 1 b: 0
k: 1 a: 1 b: 2
k: 1 a: 1 b: 3
k: 1 a: 2 b: 0
k: 1 a: 2 b: 1
k: 1 a: 2 b: 3
k: 1 a: 3 b: 0
k: 1 a: 3 b: 1
k: 1 a: 3 b: 2
```

What I want is essentially 3 choice of those 24 lines of output. 24 choose 3 = 2024 lines of output without any additional library usage. I want to do some calculations based on 3 of those 24 lines at a time.

The equivalent python code

```
import itertools    
iterable = ["k: 0 a: 0 b: 1", "k: 0 a: 0 b: 2", "k: 0 a: 0 b: 3", "k: 0 a: 1 b: 0", "k: 0 a: 1 b: 2", "k: 0 a: 1 b: 3", "k: 0 a: 2 b: 0", "k: 0 a: 2 b: 1", "k: 0 a: 2 b: 3", "k: 0 a: 3 b: 0", "k: 0 a: 3 b: 1", "k: 0 a: 3 b: 2", "k: 1 a: 0 b: 1", "k: 1 a: 0 b: 2", "k: 1 a: 0 b: 3", "k: 1 a: 1 b: 0", "k: 1 a: 1 b: 2", "k: 1 a: 1 b: 3", "k: 1 a: 2 b: 0", "k: 1 a: 2 b: 1", "k: 1 a: 2 b: 3", "k: 1 a: 3 b: 0", "k: 1 a: 3 b: 1", "k: 1 a: 3 b: 2"]
a = list(itertools.combinations(iterable, 3))
print(a)
```

demonstrates what I want. I was wondering how to do this in C++ using just the `for` loops.

Comment: the loops just produce the 24 tuples. You need a whole new loop (as you have done in python) to produce combinations of those 24 things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things easier, I'd group a `k`, `a` and `b` value together into a single object. Let's call it a K-A-B object, or a `kab`:

```
struct kab {
    int k, a, b;
};
```

Then, I'd make an `increment` function that'll take a `kab` and give us the next `kab` in the sequence. This'll allow us to condense all three of your loops down into one and make it easier to iterate from any point in the sequence. That could look like:

```
kab increment(kab obj) {
    obj.b = (obj.b + 1) % (MAX_B + 1);
    if(obj.b == 0) {
        obj.a = (obj.a + 1) % (MAX_A + 1);
        if(obj.a == 0) {
            obj.k++;
        }
    }
 
    // Ensure a != b by incrementing again if they are
    if(obj.a == obj.b) {
        return increment(obj);
    }
 
    return obj;
}
```

Lastly, it's just a matter of doing the actual increments. Here's an example:

```
while(vals.k <= MAX_K) {
    kab vals2 = increment(vals);
    while(vals2.k <= MAX_K) {
        kab vals3 = increment(vals2);
        while(vals3.k <= MAX_K) {
            std::cout << "k: " << vals.k  << " a: " << vals.a  << " b: " << vals.b  << std::endl;
            std::cout << "k: " << vals2.k  << " a: " << vals2.a  << " b: " << vals2.b  << std::endl;
            std::cout << "k: " << vals3.k  << " a: " << vals3.a  << " b: " << vals3.b  << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            vals3 = increment(vals3);
        }
        vals2 = increment(vals2);
    }
    vals = increment(vals);
}
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/9cVHuG (note that that much output causes ideone to timeout. This should work fine locally).

Comment: The values of k, a and b will change (k can be sometimes 200 and a = 200). But I assume I can just change the hardcoded 2 and 4.

Comment: @Morpheus I've updated the code snippets and the ideone link to use constants for max values to make it more obvious how the code will need to change with new values (you're basically right though). Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

If value of `k` is varying and much larger than `3`, we'll have to apply recursion. Till then 3 for loops works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> M;
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k)
        for (int a = 0; a < 4; ++a)
            for (int b = 0; b < 4; ++b)
                if (a != b)
                    M.push_back(vector<int>({ k, a, b }));

    vector<vector<int>> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)M.size() - 2; ++i)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < (int)M.size() - 1; ++j)
            for (int k = j + 1; k < (int)M.size(); ++k)
            {
                vector<int> temp;

                for (int e : M[i])
                    temp.push_back(e);
                for (int e : M[j])
                    temp.push_back(e);
                for (int e : M[k])
                    temp.push_back(e);
                res.push_back(temp);
            }

    for (const vector<int>& V : res)
    {
        for (int e : V)
            cout << e << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: K will be around 200 sometimes. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The k I'm referring to is of n choose k combination. The k in the loop is fine. My bad!

Comment: Thanks. I should have checked it more carefully. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Quick tip: instead of `i < (int)M.size() - 2`, you can do `i + 2 < M.size()`. That way you won't need the ugly `int` cast and you can even make `i` an `unsigned` or `size_t` if you wanted.